# Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Column can't be converted from factor to numeric

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, tibble

I have ten datasets that have been read from Excel files, using the **xlsx** library, and stored in tibbles. I want to merge them.

Here are example datasets. The number of variables differ between datasets, and some variables are only in one dataset. The value of the *person* variable will never overlap.

```
data1 <- tibble(person = c("A","B","C"),
    test1 = as.factor(c(1,4,5)), 
    test2 = c(14,25,10),
    test3 = c(12.5,16.0,4),
    test4 = c(16,23,21),
    test5 = as.factor(c(49,36,52)))

data2 <- tibble(person = c("D","E","F"),
    test1 = c(8,7,2), 
    test3 = c(6.5,12.0,19.5),
    test4 = as.factor(c(15,21,29)),
    test5 = as.factor(c(54,51,36)),
    test6 = c(32,32,29),
    test7 = c(13,11,10))
```

The actual datasets usually have ~50 rows and ~200 variables in them. I have tried

```
    all_data <- dplyr::bind_rows(data1,data2)
```

hoping to get this outcome

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
  person test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      A     1    14  12.5    16    49    NA    NA
2      B     4    25  16.0    23    36    NA    NA
3      C     5    10   4.0    21    52    NA    NA
4      D     8    NA   6.5    15    54    32    13
5      E     7    NA  12.0    21    51    32    11
6      F     2    NA  19.5    29    36    29    10
```

but instead I get this error

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Column `test1` can't be converted from factor to numeric
```

I have searched Stackoverflow, and I found questions regarding this, and most answers center on trying to convert the variables to another class. But I *don't care* which classes my variables have, because I will just write the merged dataset to a CSV-file or Excel file.

Isn't there some kind of simple workaround?

Comment: For this situation, the `rbindlist` seems to be working fine i.e `library(data.table);list(data1, data2) %>% rbindlist(., fill = TRUE)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think that this should work:

```
library(plyr)
all_data <- rbind.fill(data1,data2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, some SO users like to downvote answers without explaining why. In my experience, rbind.fill sometimes gives unexpected results (unexpected for me, a single wrong number pops up in the data frame). More experienced R users may explain why.

Answer (score 9):

As the file are usually small (several hundred rows) and you simply want to combine the two file and write to a new file, I think we can convert all columns to character, thus the common columns in `data1` and `data2` will have the same type.

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(mutate_all(data1, as.character), mutate_all(data2, as.character))
```

Comment: What if get the same error but in my case I have a list of tibbles (around 10 tibbles that altogether have more than 2k different columns)?  Some tibbles don't include the problematic column.

Comment: @Miha, I don't know exactly how your data looks like. does `bind_rows(lapply(tibble_list, function(dtt){mutate_all(dtt, as.character)}))` work?

Answer (score 0):

test1 in data1 is of class factor whereas in data2 is of class numeric. Combining a factor class and numeric class causes this problem. Solution either convert test1 in both data1 and data2 to factors and then use `all_data <- dplyr::bind_rows(data1,data2)`

or

`data.table::rbindlist(data1,data2)`